# Why arabic font not supported in Samsung mobiles using LWUIT?

Tags: mobile, java-me, fonts, lwuit, samsung-mobile

I have tested my mobile application on some Samsung mobiles for testing purpose(Samsung Corby b3410 and Samsung c6712). Here Arabic font not showing on these mobiles. But it will working properly on Nokia mobiles. I'm using `System font` for showing Arabic fonts. Why its not supporting on these mobiles? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: The included fonts will likely depend on the OS build that your cellular provider includes with the Samsung phones. Where is the coding question?

Comment: Oh oh. LWUIT supports Arabic font when we using Font type is `SYSTEM`. Right? And May I know why its not programming related question? Is this reason for down vote?

Comment: I have to counter that - I think the question is fine. I don't think Samsungs that you've mentioned support Arabic though :( Check their support site for example - the only language listed for Corby is English (India): http://www.samsung.com/in/support/search/supportSearchModelResult.do?menu=SP01&searchWord=Corbyb3410&default_searchInputBox_value=Enter+model+number+or+keywords&searchInputBox=Corby+b3410

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LWUIT doesn't support Arabic bitmap fonts, when the font type is 'system' we just delegate the Arabic support to the underlying OS. If the underlying phone OS doesn't include Arabic support LWUIT won't work with Arabic.

To workaround this some people have made efforts to implement Arabic bitmap fonts by modifying LWUIT to support that. We haven't incorporated any of these changes since:

a. They are very complex and language dependent.
b. They don't solve the issue of accepting input.
c. Most devices in Arabic speaking countries should support Arabic so its a pretty niche problem.

These solutions might be enough for your needs, but personally I wouldn't make the effort for that small fraction of devices.