# Arabic Font Not showing in Samsung Devices

Tags: java, android, fonts

I am getting problem with Arabic Fonts, I have some Arabic fonts and I am using from assets, and it shows properly on Non Samsung Devices. But when I run on Samsung Android device it will show broken alphabets of Arabic!

How can I solve this problem?
I want to show Arabic Language properly in all devices.

here is my code for setting font

```
       TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom); 
       Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/arabic.ttf");     
       tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Comment: How are you embedding the fonts in the assets? Also which version of Android do your Samsung devices use?

Comment: My Samsung Android version 4.0.2 and TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom); 
  Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/arabic.ttf"); 
  tv.setTypeface(face);

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information in it.

Comment: Please check the below link     [Arabic font not supported][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859879/why-arabic-font-not-supported-in-samsung-mobiles-using-lwuit

Comment: just go through this link : I hope it will help you. http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html

Comment: Thanks, This link Solve my problem, I checked this fonts support Arabic Samsung devices and other devices.